# How to remove backBarButtonItem empty space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a problem with my custom `UINavigationController` (in screenshot).[image: Custom UINavigationController]

As you can see, I've already removed the title in back button, but there's an empty space that I'm unable to remove.

Here's the code that I've used for backButtonItem:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")     
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

You probably only need one or the other though.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read correctly my question: the problem is that I have to remove the white space between back arrow and textfield. I noticed that this white space belongs to backbutton.

Comment: Just one to consider, if you remove the white space to extend your input textfield then your UI would look really terrible. Just my thoughts...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read close enough. However I think if you hide the back button, then add a leftBarButtonItem as your back arrow, and handle the back button tap with your own @IBAction, then you will achieve the look you want.  I think the issue is that the UI is still allowing the title a certain amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

if you use storyboard you should:

1. select textfield
2. go to "show the size inspector"
3. from "arrange" menu choose "Fill Container Horizontally"

done ;)

[image]

Comment: My navigation bar is a standard bar, with a XIB-based custom UIView as titleView, and the back button is only replaced backgroundImage and text set as "". I don't know what you are talking about. If you send me a screenshot, I can accept your answer if it's ok.

Comment: It doesn't work...:( I've got the same result as before :(